# Continous listening of Messages from Azure Service Bus Queues via REST possible?

Tags: rest, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am able to perform REST DELETE operation to receive and delete messages from Azure service bus queues.To perform this we need to externally call the REST api.
Is there any feature to perform polling,as soon as the message is available in the queue via REST API, we should pickup the message automatically with out external invocation to initiate the message pickup from queue.

Continuous listening of messages from queue via REST is possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Continuous listening of messages from queue via REST is possible?

I **don't** think that there is a way just send rest a request that could continuous listen of messages from queue. As send a REST API request and just a response.

But we could  continuous listen of messages from queue with Azure Webjob, Azure function or Azure logical App to trigger Service bus queue message. For more information you could refer to following tutorials.

[Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus)

[Azure WebJob Service Bus trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Service-Bus)